# How to I find documents in mongo which does not contain a array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, find

I have 2 kinds of documents in my mongodb

first is like this  with a array of interests

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7e4c3ad2b96e109e0d3842"),
    "email" : "user@hotmail.com",
    "interesse" : [ 
        "interest 1", 
        "interest 2", 
        "interest 3"
    ],
    "data" : 20170130,
    "name" : "testename",
    "gender" : "F"
}
```

and the second is like this with a big  string of interests separated by /

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7e4cbbd2b96e109e6b748f"),
    "email" : "user2@gmail.com",
    "interesse" : "interest 3 / interest 4 / interest 5 / interest 6 / interest 7",
    "data" : 20190122,
    "name" : "user2",
    "gender" : "F"
}
```

I want to select only the data with the big string.. so i can apply a my "stringToArray" function ..

using
`.find({interesse:{$type:'array'}})` i can get all the type1
but if i use

```
.find({interesse:{$type:'string'}}) i will get all  registers in my base.
```

using

```
.find({interesse:{$type:{$not:'array'}}})
```

i get

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "type must be represented as a number or a string",
    "code" : 14,
    "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
}
```

what can i do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
.find({interesse:{$not:{$type:'array'}}})
```